# maven 3 surefire and maven gwt exclude / include problems

Tags: maven, gwt, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a root pom configured with the maven-surefire-plugin and a gwt module pom configured with the gwt-maven-plugin.
After upgrading to Maven 3 I get strange errors.

The project is similar configured like described here: [Separate GwtTest tests from standard unit tests](https://web.archive.org/web/20130112082646/http://mojo.codehaus.org:80/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/testing.html)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
    <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>listener</name>
        <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <argLine>-server -Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled</argLine>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*GwtTest*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

AND

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
  <modules>
    <module>my.app.gwt</module>
  </modules>
  <runTarget>/</runTarget>
  <extraJvmArgs>-Xss512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M</extraJvmArgs>
  <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</hostedWebapp>
  <includes>**/*GwtTestSuite.java</includes>
  <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
  <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
  <persistentunitcache>false</persistentunitcache>
  <draftCompile>${gwt.draftCompile}</draftCompile>
  <deploy>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/deploy</deploy>
  <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking> 
  <mode>htmlunit</mode>
  <skipTests>${skipGwtTests}</skipTests></configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>gwt-compile</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>compile</phase>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>gwt-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>test</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

It works with maven 2 but with maven 3 I get :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:test (gwt-test) on project my-webapp: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:test: When configuring a basic element the configuration cannot contain any child elements. Configuration element 'excludes'. -> [Help 1]
```

It seems that the gwt plugin can't parse the hierarchical style of the surefire plugin.

It only compiles if I set all excludes/includes inside the gwt plugin as one comma separated string line, but that doesn't work for me, because I need to exclude the gwt tests globally, and include them locally.

The include/exclude sections get merged however, so that the two incompatible  syntax definitions won't work together.

I hope somebody can give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your GWTTestCases using straight Maven Surefire, see [this link](http://jectbd.com/?p=380).

Comment: I am guessing that still does not explain difference between maven 2 and maven 3 and the hierarchical stuff.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I would like to solve the problem without changing my project's characteristics, I just want to upgrade to maven 3